# How do I solve $(py - qy^{n}) + y' = 0$ using an integrating factor?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If $p$ and $q$ are functions of $x$, then the DE
$$(py - qy^{n}) + y' = 0$$ admits an integrating factor of the form $X(x)Y(y)$. Find the functions $X$ and $Y$.

I got trouble when I tried to start from the equation $$M_{y} = N_{x}$$ and hoped to get something useful from new arrangements of terms in this equation, but failed. So in which direction should I think further when I faced this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternate approach to this type of problem. Divide the equation by $y^n$ and get

$$py^{1-n}-q+y'y^{-n}=0$$

Let $z(x)$ be defined as $z=y^{1-n}$, which gives $z'=(1-n)y^{-n}y'$$ and so

$$pz-q+\frac{1}{1-n}z'=0$$

Now this is a linear equation, so you can solve for $z$ and then recover $y$.

**Edit** Apologies for the late reply, but here is one way to do this using the integrating factor (albeit it is quite cumbersome by comparison)>

Let's suppose we can multiply this equation by some product $X(x)Y(y)$ to make this an exact equation. Multiplying gives

$$XY(py-qy^n)dx+XYdy=0$$

From here, we require that the partial derivative with respect to $y$ of the left term is equal to the partial derivative with respect to $x$ of the right term. This means that

$$XY'(py-qy^n)+XY(p-nqy^{n-1})=X'Y$$

Dividing both side by $XY$ gives

$$\frac{Y'}{Y}(py-qy^n)+p-nqy^{n-1}=\frac{X'}{X}$$

We group terms as

$$p\left(\frac{Y'}{Y}y+1\right)-q\left(\frac{Y'}{Y}y^n+ny^{n-1}\right)=\frac{X'}{X}$$

The right side is purely a function of $x$, while the left side is mixed. This means that abstractly all of the $y$'s on the left side must somehow disappear. This can only happen if the terms contained in the parentheses are constant, for if they were functions of $y$ then there would be no guarantee that this equation holds for any choice of $p$ and $q$. The first equation then should read

$$\frac{Y'}{Y}y+1=C$$

and the second equation reads

$$\frac{Y'}{Y}y^n+ny^{n-1}=D$$

We solve the first equation: separating gives

$$\frac{Y'}{Y}=\frac{C-1}{y}$$

Integrating gives

$$\ln|Y|=(C-1)\ln|y|+K$$

Solving for $Y$ gives

$$Y=Ky^{C-1}$$

We place this into the second equation and get

$$(C-1)y^{n-1}+ny^{n-1}=D$$

The left side is a function of $y$ and can only be constant when the coefficients sum to zero, giving

$$D=0,\;\;\;\;C=1-n$$

We then let

$$Y=Ky^{-n}$$

This function satisfies the two equations

$$\frac{Y'}{Y}y+1=1-n,\;\;\;\;\frac{Y'}{Y}y^n+ny^{n-1}=0$$

We replace these back into the grouped terms and get

$$p(1-n)-q(0)=\frac{X'}{X}$$

Integrating and solving gives

$$X=e^{(1-n)\int pdx}$$

The integrating factor is then

$$XY=\frac{1}{y^n}e^{(1-n)\int pdx}$$

The case of $n=1$ is slightly different, giving $XY=1/y$.

Comment: Thanks, however, the problem is to find $X(x)$ and $Y(y)$.

Comment: You could also name it as Bernoulli equation.

Answer (score 0):

Change the equation into
$$ 1+\frac1{py- qy^{n}} y'=0. $$
Clearly
$$ M=1,N=\frac1{py- qy^{n}} $$
and then
$$ M_y= N_x=0. $$
So
$$ F(x,y)=\int Mdx+C(y)=x+C(y). $$
Letting $F_y=N$, one has
$$ 1+C'(y)=\frac1{py- qy^{n}} $$
or
$$ C'(y)=-1+\frac{1}{py-qy^n}. $$
It is not hard to obtain
$$ C(y)=-y-\frac{1}{p(n-1)} \ln(q-p y^{1-n}).$$
and the solution is
$$ x-y-\frac{1}{p(n-1)} \ln(q-p y^{1-n})=C. $$